# Android OpenGL : How to you move an object

Tags: android, opengl-es

I would like to move an object from one position on the screen to another position using the OpenGL API's.  How do we do that ? Can someone help me with some pointer's or a sample snippet.

Comment: This is too broad a question for stackoverflow. There are a number of OpenGL / OpenGL ES tutorials on the web.

Comment: @fadden : I truly believe that the question is specific , may be if i wrote the question now i would have written "What API in android would you use to move a texture from one position to another position using OpenGL ES". Do you agree ?

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the answer and it works.

[Reference from Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/microedition/khronos/opengles/GL10.html#glTranslatef(float,%20float,%20float))

To move a texture using openGL, you can use the above function which will accept the new coordinates (relative to the previous coordinates of the Texture). Hope this helps.